# Pyramid from letters in string

Tags: python

I have begun programming with Python and I made this simple program drawing stars in the shape of the pyramid:

```
print("Put in the number of stars")
row = int(input())
letters = "python"

for i in range(row):
    stars = i*2-1
    spaces = row - i
    print(" "* spaces + "*"* stars)
```

How can I make this pyramid out of the word python instead of stars?  I mean this:

```
     p
    pyt
   python
 pythonpyt
pythonpytho
```

and so on?

Thanks for help guys.

Comment: Please show us your attempt on making pyramid of words , not only stars.

Comment: And also ,  the order of the word is not constant. What is the algorithm? `pyt` > `python` but how? as `pythonpyt` > `pythonpytho` not `pythonpython` . **-1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modification to the original post:

```
print("Put in the number of stars")
row = int(input())
letters = "python"
l = letters * row

for i in range(1, row + 1):
    stars = i*2-1
    p = l[0:stars]
    spaces = row - i
    print(" "* spaces + p)
```

output:

```
Put in the number of stars
10
         p
        pyt
       pytho
      pythonp
     pythonpyt
    pythonpytho
   pythonpythonp
  pythonpythonpyt
 pythonpythonpytho
pythonpythonpythonp
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.cycle` and `itertools.islice` to build the rows:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle

n = 5

for i in range(n):
    print((n-i)*' ' + ''.join(islice(cycle('python'), 2*i+1)))
```

prints:

```
     p                                                                                                              
    pyt                                                                                                             
   pytho                                                                                                            
  pythonp                                                                                                           
 pythonpyt
```